# Translate date("d F Y (H:i) function php

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I'm brazilian and there's a wordpress plugin that uses

```
" . date("d F Y (H:i)",$date) . "
```

Output: **16 January 2013 (00:54)**

But it should be 16 Janeiro 2013 (00:54), in portuguese... How can I change it?

PS: I think maybe the date is set by an external file provided by the plugin creator :p I'm not sure though

Comment: Try to add more context when asking... Where is `$date` coming from? Is this a theme template file? Are you using the locale `pt_BR` in `wp-config.php`? What's the Date Format in `/wp-admin/options-general.php`?

Comment: @brasofilo, it's a theme file http://pastebin.com/CZpfBQpF - Just added setlocale(LC_ALL, “pt_BR”, “ptb”); to wp-config.php and nothing happened, and there are millions of references to Date in options-general.php, but none regarding local/language, as far as I know... It's the default options-general.php from wordpress 3.4.2

Comment: That doesn't look like a Theme template **at all**... And it's grabbing `$date` from a `$_POST` value, so hard to tell the origin. You should do a `var_dump` on it. ::: I meant `http://example.com/wp-admin/options-general.php` and not the PHP file itself. ::: Seems that you don't know `WPLANG`. This page is quite useful: [Editing_wp-config.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php). ::: You may want to read this Q&A too: [How do you debug plugins?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/145/12615).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

WordPress has [`date_i18n`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/date_i18n/) to retrieve the date in localized format, based on timestamp.

Try:

```
echo date_i18n("d F Y (H:i)", $timestamp);
```

WordPress has an extensive page on how to [format date and time](https://wordpress.org/support/article/formatting-date-and-time/).

Comment: yayyy!! It works like a charm!! Great solution, simple and effective! Thanks a LOT man!! Saved 2 days of work!!!!!!

Comment: I tried every possible way to do this with native PHP and for some reason it just would not work.. but with this WordPress function it works perfectly as expected!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you! The guys working on WP are doing an awesome job :)

Comment: I have a plugin who show date from RSS fetch, but nothing work to translate it. the plugin use this forma: $item->get_date('F j, Y - g:i a');

Comment: wtf: 01 enero 1970 (00:00)

Comment: @ValRob That's unix time zero. is your `$date` correct?

Answer (score 3):

For the french language I use this

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fra');

echo strftime("%A %d %B %Y",time());
```

For in portuguese

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ptg');  //

echo strftime("%A %d %B %Y",time());
```

see [Language Strings Country/Region Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cdax410z(v=vs.90).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) already answers this:

> To format dates in other languages, you should use the setlocale() and
>   strftime() functions instead of date().

And `strftime` says that the way to do what is by using [`setlocale`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php):

> Format the time and/or date according to locale settings. Month and
>   weekday names and other language-dependent strings respect the current
>   locale set with setlocale().

That said, the C locale-aware functions do not provide sufficient functionality for languages that [have cases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_case). In such situations (i.e. most of the time) you need to roll your own.

Comment: I tried to add `<?php  
setlocale(LC_ALL, “pt_BR”, “ptb”);
?>` to the header.php, inside <head> tags, but it didn't work, also inside the plugin file and stuff

Comment: @user2056484: Locale names are dependent on your server's OS. There is no guarantee that these particular locales are installed on your own. In general, `setlocale` is insufficient for any serious work and you will probably have to find another solution.

Comment: Hmm, What do you suggest @Jon? I'm trying in a lot of ways here :p Here's the script's pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/CZpfBQpF -- Plus: I've tried to translate locale.php, no success :/

Comment: @user2056484: I suggest finding a suitable implementation online (most self-respecting PHP frameworks should have one) or writing your own.

Comment: Jon, i'm noob at php...I'm not lazy, but I have 30 items on my check-list to fix and present the client the website, and I don't know what to do :p I think i'll skip this  :/