# How to resolve Strings should have translatable content in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, lint

I am trying to fix the linting issue here is code.

```
function get_the_breadcrumb() {
if ( ! is_front_page() ) {
    // Start the breadcrumb with a link to your homepage.
    echo '<div class="o__breadcrumb">';
    echo '<a href="';
    echo esc_html( get_option( 'home' ) );
    echo '"> Home';
    echo '</a> <span> ';
    echo esc_html( Load::atom( 'icons/breadcrumb_arrow' ) );
    echo '</span>';

    // Check if the current page is a category, an archive or a single page. If so show the category or archive name.
    if ( is_category() || is_single() ) {
        the_category( 'title_li=' );
    } elseif ( is_archive() || is_single() ) {
        if ( is_day() ) {
            /* translators: %s: text term */
            printf( esc_html( __( '%s', 'text_domain' ) ), esc_html( get_the_date() ) );
        } elseif ( is_month() ) {
            /* translators: %s: text term */
            printf( esc_html( __( '%s', 'text_domain' ) ), get_the_date( _x( 'F Y', 'monthly archives date format', 'text_domain' ) ) );
        } elseif ( is_year() ) {
            /* translators: %s: text term */
            printf( esc_html( __( '%s', 'text_domain' ) ), get_the_date( _x( 'Y', 'yearly archives date format', 'text_domain' ) ) );
        } else {
            esc_attr_e( 'Blog Archives', 'text_domain' );
        }
    }
    // If the current page is a single post, show its title with the separator.
    if ( is_single() ) {
        echo '<span>';
        echo esc_html( Load::atom( 'icons/breadcrumb_arrow' ) );
        echo '</span>';
        the_title();
    }
    // If the current page is a static page, show its title.
    if ( is_page() ) {
        echo the_title();
    }
    // if you have a static page assigned to be you posts list page. It will find the title of the static page and display it. i.e Home >> Blog.
    if ( is_home() ) {
        global $post;
        $page_for_posts_id = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
        if ( $page_for_posts_id ) {
            $post = get_page( $page_for_posts_id );
            setup_postdata( $post );
            the_title();
            rewind_posts();
        }
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
}
```

Linting response

```
FOUND 3 ERRORS AFFECTING 3 LINES
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 193 | ERROR | Strings should have translatable content
 196 | ERROR | Strings should have translatable content
 199 | ERROR | Strings should have translatable content
```

Line number 193

```
printf( esc_html( __( '%s', 'text_domain' ) ), esc_html( get_the_date() ) );
```

Line number 196

```
printf( esc_html( __( '%s', 'text_domain' ) ), get_the_date( _x( 'F Y', 'monthly archives date format', 'text_domain' ) ) );
```

Line number 199

```
printf( esc_html( __( '%s', 'text_domain' ) ), get_the_date( _x( 'Y', 'yearly archives date format', 'text_domain' ) ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have `%s` as the text inside the translation function call `__(...)`, which is not translatable.

Instead you should have your printf() call *inside* the translation call, so the translator can actually see what the heck you're trying to translate.

**But,** you shouldn't be trying to translate the date this way. It won't work because the date is always changing and the way `__()` translation works is by matching the exact string passed in to a translation. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821998/translate-dated-f-y-hi-function-php), you should use `date_i18n`

And *why* are you trying to translate the date formatting strings you are passing to `get_the_date`, those are code values used by php, they don't change based on where you are. Translating these can only cause you problems.

You also call `esc_html` twice on line 193.

**So,** instead you should write your lines of code like so:

Line number 193

`esc_html( date_i18n( get_the_date() ) );`

Line number 196

`esc_html( date_i18n( get_the_date('F Y') ) );`

Line number 199

`esc_html( date_i18n( get_the_date( 'Y' ) ) );`

*Note,* I don't think the `esc_html` calls are actually necessary here, since the internals is just WordPress functions that only return dates... no html should be in there